# listview items not showing up in android

Tags: android, listview

I am beginner in Android application development and there might be similiar question on stackoverflow but I am unable to find the exact solution to this problem.I have tried many links on SO. Help Appreciated. Let me know if any other file needs to be uploaded.

Here is the listview output
   [Listview output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/253bJ.png)

I'm pretty sure the items are inserted in the listview because I get the following output when i toast the item at 0.[Toast.makeText to display item0 of listview l1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aiopb.png)
So no problem with inserting data into listview. the problem probably is in displaying

```
// fragment_cart layout - where the listview is stored.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listview_cart"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Cartlist_layout - the structure of listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

//addtocart_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="Total :    Rs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="4"
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />

<TextView
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="142dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_marginEnd="45dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="ItemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CartDialog - the java file

```
public class CartDialog extends DialogFragment {
    String item;
    TextView iname,t11;
    EditText qty;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View view;
    NumberPicker numberPicker;
    public static int sprice[]={40,50,60,25,30,30,25,25,20,20,20,15,15};
    public String names[]=new String[]{"Item1","Item2","Item3"};
    public ListView l1;
    int i=0;
    List itemName;
    LinearLayout rl;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        itemName=new ArrayList();
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.addtocart_layout,null);
        rl = (LinearLayout)view.inflate(this.getContext(), R.layout.fragment_cart,null);
        //#s1 This code is for some other functionality.  
        iname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        iname.setText(MyMenu.item1);
        int id=Integer.parseInt(MyMenu.childid);
        qty=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        t11=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
            t11.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString())*sprice[id]));
    qty.addTextChangedListener(
            new TextWatcher() {
                int id=Integer.parseInt(MyMenu.childid);
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    String qty_value=qty.getText().toString();
                    if(!qty_value.equals(""))
                        t11.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(qty_value)*sprice[id]));
                    else
                        t11.setText("");

                }
            }
    );
     #s1 ends here

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(view).setPositiveButton("Add to Cart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            onAddToCart();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
public void onAddToCart(){
//PLAUSIBLE PROBLEM HERE - i think, Something must be wrong here   
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(),R.layout.cartlist_layout,names);
    l1=(ListView)rl.findViewById(R.id.listview_cart);
    l1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Added to Cart:"+l1.getItemAtPosition(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: You are using custom layout in the list but you have not defined a way to match up your view (R.layout.cartlist_layout) with data (names). Try to search for how to use custom adapter would help.

Answer (score 0):

When you inflate your fragment_cart layout you are not attaching it to anything, that's why you can't see your results.

From the image you showed, it seems that the fragment_cart layout is actually part of the activity.

You could do something like this

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public Fragment mCartFragment;
    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //...

        mCartFragment = new CartFragment();
        // Attach this fragment to your main activity
    }
}
```

**Cart Fragment**

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {

    View mView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle s) {

        // inflate fragment_cart here
        mView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_cart,
                container,
                false
        );

        return mView;
    }
}
```

And in your addToCart() method (assuming MainActivity is responsible for launching the CartDialog):

```
public void addToCart(){
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
    View fragmentCartView = mainActivity.mCartFragment.getView();
    if(fragmentCartView != null){
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(),R.layout.cartlist_layout,names);
        l1 = fragmentCartView.findViewById(R.id.listview_cart);
        l1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Added to Cart:"+l1.getItemAtPosition(0),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Now, I don't like this solution very much because you are coupling the CartDialog to the main activity, but I didn't want to change your code too much.

Comment: just did it. addtocart_layout

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: I have to know where your listview_cart is attached, if it's not attached to anything you will never see the results

Comment: the fragment_cart is part of the MainActivity.

Comment: the listview_cart(id of the listview) is in the fragment_cart fragment.

Comment: Im stuck on this for 2 days now. please help :')

Comment: Inside your main activity, did you store your fragment in a variable?

Comment: No, did not store in a variable. How do i do that? And how will that help ?

Comment: Check my answer again, If my new answer doesn't suit you, I don't think I can help you more

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your method :
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();